# Making the horizontal scroll wheel work in a VCL application, even with a Logitech MX Master mouse

Tags: delphi, horizontal-scrolling, vcl, mousewheel, delphi-10.3-rio

I am attempting to implement support for the horizontal scroll wheel in various of my own custom VCL controls, but it seems to be tricky, at least if you are using the Logitech MX Master mouse.

To be concrete, let's drop an ordinary `TScrollBox` on a form and add a few child controls:

[image: Screenshot of a form with a scroll box full of child controls.]

Without adding any code, I am not able to scroll it vertically using the primary mouse wheel. Scrolling the wheel, nothing happens, as expected.

However, if I resize the form to make the horizontal scroll bar appear and use the thumb wheel on my MX Master mouse to scroll horizontally, a strange thing happens: the horizontal scroll bar becomes unthemed and moves according to the wheel, but the client area isn't scrolled:

[image: Video showing strange horizontal scrollbar behaviour.]

That's odd, isn't it?

Well, by implementing an `OnMouseWheel` handler, it is trivial to make the main scroll wheel scroll vertically:

```
procedure TForm1.ScrollBox1MouseWheel(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState;
  WheelDelta: Integer; MousePos: TPoint; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  ScrollBox1.VertScrollBar.Position := ScrollBox1.VertScrollBar.Position - WheelDelta;
  Handled := True
end;
```

To get the secondary scroll wheel to do horizontal scrolling, I try

```
procedure TScrollBox.WndProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  case Message.Msg of
    WM_MOUSEHWHEEL:
      begin
        HorzScrollBar.Position := HorzScrollBar.Position + TWMMouseWheel(Message).WheelDelta;
        Message.Result := 0;
      end;
  else
    inherited;
  end;
end;
```

to no avail.

However, if I change `Message.Result` to `1` (ignoring [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-mousehwheel) which states otherwise), it works as expected as long as the mouse is not above any windowed child control.

I seem to recall that my old Microsoft Touch Mouse was able to scroll horizontally without any issues. Also, Google suggests that many end users have issues with horizontal scrolling using the MX Master. Still, I am able to use my MX Master to scroll horizontally in web browsers, Microsoft Office, Notepad, and Paint.

What is the correct way to implement support for horizontal scrolling? And, if the correct approach is incompatible with the MX Master, is there any way to work around this incompatibility? After all, it is a common pointing device from a major manufacturer.

Comment: You know you can use Shift + Wheel for horizontal scrolling, right?

Comment: @Olivier: Sure, I could use that, but I still would prefer if the dedicated wheel worked as intended in my controls.